# VSCode webview viewtype unexpectedly changed. Implementation detail or something to depend on?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

My extension creates a webview via `vscode.window.createWebview`.

The webview is currently active. I query the `viewType` via `vscode.window.tabGroups` API:

```
const activeTab = vscode.window.tabGroups.activeTabGroup.activeTab;
const activeTabViewType = activeTab?.input instanceof vscode.TabInputWebview && (activeTab?.input as vscode.TabInputWebv
```

I expect to see the same string as passed to `createWebview`, e.g. `eee`. Instead, I see `mainThreadWebview-eee`.

I'm curious if `mainThreadWebview-` prefix is an implementation detail or something I can safely rely on.

Related: github [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/201884).